# Stopping spam-related bounced emails

Tags: email, postfix, spam, email-bounces

One of my e-mail customers is currently on the receiving end of massive amounts of delivery failure notices as a "Nigerian scammer" seems to be using her address as its MAIL FROM field.

A lot of it is marked as spam by the SpamAssassin running on the inbound server (if they include the original message).

I added a manual content filter which removes more of the stuff.

I also temporarily blacklisted a few of the most active sources of bounce emails as they weren't servers any of my customers were likely to exchange actual e-mail with.

That has reduced the amount of spurious delivery failure notices my customer receives, however she's still getting ~1-2 such notices per minute.

Is there anything more I can do to help her get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail your customer is receiving is called [backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28e-mail%29). Simply knowing that people call it that might help your Google searches for potential fixes. [Here's a ruleset](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/VBounceRuleset) for SpamAssassin that might help.

Answer (score 4):

The other main thing that can be done to prevent backscatter is to publish SPF records for your customer's domain.  The format is detailed at [the OpenSPF project's website](http://www.openspf.org/), but in essence you publish through the DNS a list of servers that are authorized to send mail from your customer's domain, and then make it clear that no others are permitted to do so (`-all`).

It's up to the recipient to check the SPF records before accepting a spam forged as coming from your customer's domain, but many do, and a hard failure (`-all`) will cause those recipients to reject the incoming email before it ever gets as far as making a bounce message.

I found that publishing SPF records for my domains immediately cut the backscatter by a big fraction - perhaps 65%? - and it fell much further over time, probably because intelligent spammers will avoid picking fake-sender domains that are going to be instantly rejected by mailservers with clue.

Comment: When I began receiving backscatter, I setup SPF records.  Backscatter dropped significantly, and use of the domain for Spma stopped.  I also setup an email alias for the problem userid and forced a failure on it.  After years the userid still receives occasional spam addressed to it.

Comment: I already have SPF records which only permit email from my outbound gateways and deny the rest - but thanks.